# Update Java object with a Hashmap

Tags: java

I have a model with some properties e.g.

```
public class Example
{
long id;
String a, b;
int c, d;
boolean e;
}
```

Now I want to create a method like this

```
public void update(long id, Map<String, Object> properties)
{
....
}
```

in this properties map I want to have sth like

properties.put("a","Test");
properties.put("c", 8);

I'm not exactly sure on how to achieve this.

at the end I want to do sth like this:

```
Example e = new Example(....);
.....
e.update(5L,properties);
```

can some1 point me to the correct path? I cant figure out a searchterm that doesnt lead me to the Properties or HashMap entries.

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to look at reflection. Although in many cases that's not actually a good idea...

Comment: Why do you have to use fields. Use map as a private field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for the keyword [*reflection*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). With reflective access you would write your update method like that:

```
public void update(long id, Map<String, Object> properties) {
    Object obj = getObjectById(id); // you have to implement that method
    for (String property : properties.keySet()) {
        Field field = obj.getClass().getField(property);
        field.set(obj, properties.get(property));
    }
}
```

Note, that I did not declare or handle any exceptions that come along with reflection.

---

A completely other issue: Why do you want to do it this way? Using reflection to update fields of an object smells like a real design issue. You really should consider another model.

Comment: Maybe I am having a design issue. My actual case is that I use Ebean to map a model into a database and populate it via REST. Now I want to enable the update properties method for any object (identified by Id) I get a JSON object with the updated properties and than have to edit it. Would there be a better way to achieve that? Sorry that I didnt state this in the initial question, wanted to keep it simple

Comment: Seems like a legal usage of reflection. In fact, many frameworks that map classes to database tables writing objects into them simply use reflection for that.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer and will use it (there is already a getObjectById method provided by the Ebean Framwork).

Comment: just a note for your solution in line 4 it has to be obj.getClass().getField(..... right? maybe you can fix that so others will see a working solution.

Comment: @SebastianD Thanks. I bugfixed it.

Comment: another usefull hint. getField("...") works for public Fields. If you are using private fields with getter/setter methods (as usual) you need the method getDeclaredField("...")